# Get css width from a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a string that I want to display on a web page that is dynamically passed in. I want to be able to dynamically determine the css width needed to display this string and then wrap it in an html element with the exact size needed to display it.

I am currently using javascript and dojo, so answers using those two are fine, but anything else won't work.

**More Detail**
I guess I should clarify. I want to display the string in an input field, so not as simple as a div (I think at least)

Comment: Hmm, but if you wrap a tag (maybe a `<div>` or `<span>`) around the string... wouldn't you then be able to find the pixel width of that particular string by checking the `<div>` or `<span>` that surrounds the string?

Comment: But that would require it already being on the page. Is there a way to do this before putting it on the page?

Comment: Having an extra span on the page wouldn't hurt as long as it is hidden.

Comment: @Alex. In some cases, a hidden element's width would be 0 regardless.

Comment: @Quickredfox. I know there are some problems with hidden elements. But couldn't you put a div inside another div with css-styles width:0, height:0 and overflow:hidden and get the actual width of the string from the inner div?

Comment: @Alex Most likely. I was simply pointing out the gotcha.

Comment: @Alex, the element the OP wants sized is an `<input>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to set the `<input>` length to show all characters in the string, you can set it like so:

```
var myString = "abcdefg"; // this is what got input dynamically
var myInputElement = document.getElementById('someInput');
myInputElement.size = myString.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since usually a good measure of characters are by em.

You can do this;

```
var element = Document.getElementById("ID");
element.style.length = element.value.length + " em";
```

Comment: `document` is not capitalized.

Comment: I've never used the `style.length`. Can you point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that before calculating the string's pixel width with regards to it's character count you have to somehow be aware of the metrics on the font used.

If then, you were to take the input string, wrap it in a <span>, embed it in the document, calculate the element's width, then remove the span and add the value to it's final destination you'd have a pretty decent projection of the intended width as long as your span has the same font style rules as the destination element.

If you want to get really fancy and technical about it, then the HTML 5 <canvas> tag is your friend.

A good article to better understand the complexity of font metrics in javascript which will also help you solve this: http://mudcu.be/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/#measure

Comment: It all boils down to font metrics, indeed. I cannot figure out why this answer has not gotten any up-votes. Actually, I understand 'CSS width' in the original question as: 'width by pixels' (or em's or anything else).

Comment: Because the original question is badly titled. I did answer the question asked, but not the question meant (apparently, seeing as chosen answer has nothing to do with CSS)

Answer (score -1):

you can create an element and put some callback in it's load event

```
var span = $("<span/>").text("your input").load(function(e){
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

this way you can get the current width. don't define any width for the span element and don't float.